# Insert word document to another word document without changing the format VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

First I copy a word document doc1 to a new word document with it format via a button on a userform. Second I insert at the end of this word document (filled with doc1) a new word document doc2 (doc1 and doc2 got text and table and various colors). Each time I pressed a button on another userform to put doc2, I lose the format of doc2.

Here my code:

```
Dim docSource As Document
Dim docTarget As Document
Set docTarget = ActiveDocument
Set docSource = Documents.Open(strFilename)
' Add the content of docSource to docTarget
docTarget.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
docTarget.Content.InsertAfter (docSource.Range.FormattedText)
docSource.Close (0)
```

I just don't want to lose the format coming from another word document (doc2).
There is a lot of information online, but I didn't find the one which could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW most straight-forward for inserting one document into another is to use the `InsertFile` method so that the document to be inserted doesn't even need to be opened.

The problem with the approach in the question is this

```
docTarget.Content.InsertAfter (docSource.Range.FormattedText)
```

It's necessary to use the `FormattedText` property on both sides. It's also better to use `Range` objects, at least on the "target" side, since `InsertAfter` can't work together with `FormattedText`. (`CollapseEnd` doesn't do anything in the code in the question because it's not applied to an independent `Range` object.)

The following should work

```
Dim rngTarget as Word.Range
Set rngTarget = docTarget.Content
rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rngTarget.FormattedText = docSource.Content.FormattedText
```

This will be faster than using `Selection` and the screen won't "flicker". It will also leave the user's Clipboard intact.

The only time `Selection.Copy` is the right thing to use is when *document properties* need to come across: headers, footers, page size, etc. `FormattedText` won't copy *section-level* properties, only `Range` properties.

Comment: That's great. It works very well. I tried to replace rngTarget by docTargetContent to simplify with 2 lines instead of 4, but it didn't work. I am not sure to understand why in spite of your nice explanations or is it because rngTarget need to be an independent  Range object?.

Comment: @JLuc01 It needs to be its own `Range` object. Otherwise, you're still referencing the entire content of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using copy and paste special:

Try the following:

```
    Sub PasteWithFormat()

        Dim docSource As Document
        Dim docTarget As Document
        Set docTarget = ActiveDocument
        Set docSource = Documents.Open(strFileName)

        docSource.Select
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Copy
        docTarget.Select
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)

        docSource.Close

        Set docSource = Nothing
        Set docTarget = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working very well and I understand the logic. I am just surprise you are using Select/Selection as in my previous question/post, it was not advisable to use it, not a good coding practice apparently.

Comment: Yeah, it's not, but for what you are doing its quick and easy.