# vba word 2016 saveas document without changing module name

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I suspect my strategy is incorrect as I can't seem to apply my search results for the keywords I've used over the last few days. ( [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496552]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496552%5D) seems to be the closest. )

I am able to populate a single document from the two forms I've built and save it under a new name

```
    ...
    MsgBox "Saving as " & aFullPath
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=aFullPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

But that changes the name of my parent document that contains my forms (Word2016 document name: waiver.docm). In practice, that won't be a problem because the user will not be saving "waiver.docm" except by accident.

But that's why I think my approach is wrong.

Ideally my VBA code would

1. Load a protoype waiver template with the page heading, bookmarks and table as I have now in my waiver.docm.
2. Upon filling that template, append another waiver template as a new page.
3. And return control to the form
4. Repeat above two steps of appending of sheets until the user indicates completion (e.g. "Finish" command button). Typically after 1 to 4 pages
5. Print and save the entire document.

Right now I interrupt the process after each page to force my prospective user to print and save the document (and under a unique name).

Comment: A template has a .dotm extension. Using a template will ensure that the user does not save changes, even accidentally. You can use Building Blocks to add  the content for new waivers, but you will not be successful using bookmarks. Bookmark names *must* be unique.

Comment: Good to know about the dotm. Will check out building blocks. In the meantime The bookmarks would be unique to the single page template. If I could figure out how to load that template as an appended page, Might there be an unique address for the bookmarks such as a unique document "page" identifier?

Comment: Although the bookmark names may be unique initially, once you add the extra content they won’t be. The only identifier for bookmarks is the name.

Comment: In researching building blocks I found  this bookmark example and comment Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmAddress").Range
      oRng.Text = strTemp
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmAddress", oRng
...
where orng is define as word.range. The authors comment (which I haven't tried):
Whenever you place data "in" a bookmark instead of "at" a bookmark you must redefine the bookmark range. This destroys the bookmark and another one with the same name must be added at the redefined range.